# Primefaces extensions timer

Tags: primefaces, timer, momentjs, primefaces-extensions

I'm trying to make primefaces extentions countdown timer in format something like this:

***Time remaning: 3 days, 01 : 15 : 22***

So i added pe:timer component and set format like this:

```
<pe:timer id="time_remaning" timeout="800" format="DDD [days,] HH:mm:ss" immediate="true"/>
```

But its not working as expected. I'm getting: 
***1 days, 00 : 13 : 20***

but "days" part of timeout should be 0 and not 1. Do i have error in my formater? I got formater parameters from [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) as decribed in documentation.

Or do I need to use custom formatFunction for this example or is there a way to do this just with formater?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not make it to work using formater so i used functionFormater to get the job done.

Here is my .xhtml code:

```
<pe:timer id="time_remaning" timeout="#{myBean.getTimeForTimeoutInSeconds()}" 
    formatFunction="return formatMe(value);" />
```

And the .js format function:

```
window.formatMe = function (value) {
    var numDays = Math.floor(value / 86400);
    var numHours = Math.floor((value % 86400) / 3600);
    var numMinutes = Math.floor(((value % 86400) % 3600) / 60);
    var numSeconds = ((value % 86400) % 3600) % 60;
    return numDays + " dni, " + pad(numHours, 2) + " : "
        + pad(numMinutes, 2) + " : " + pad(numSeconds, 2) + " ";
}

function pad(num, size) {
    var s = num+"";
    while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
    return s;
}
```